# Springdoc add automaticaly response based on return class

Tags: springdoc, springdoc-openui

I am migrating some code from springfox to springdoc. The code from springfox has a functionality to make the documentation of http 200 response automaticaly based on return class.

I am trying to achieve that using Operation customizer like

```
@Component
public static class OkResponseCustomizer implements org.springdoc.core.customizers.OperationCustomizer {
    @Autowired
    OpenAPI openAPI;


    @Override
    public Operation customize(Operation operation, HandlerMethod handlerMethod) {
        Class<?> returnType = handlerMethod.getMethod().getReturnType();
        ResolvedSchema resolvedSchema = ModelConverters.getInstance().resolveAsResolvedSchema(new AnnotatedType(returnType));
            String schemaName = resolvedSchema.schema.getName();
                           ApiResponses apiResponses = operation.getResponses();
            if (Objects.isNull(apiResponses.get("200"))) {
                apiResponses.addApiResponse("200", createApiResponse("ok", resolvedSchema.schema));
            }
            openAPI.getComponents().addSchemas(schemaName, resolvedSchema.schema);
        return operation;
    }
}
private static ApiResponse createApiResponse(String message, Schema schema) {
     MediaType mediaType = new MediaType();
      mediaType.schema(schema);
      return new ApiResponse().description(message)
             .content(new Content().addMediaType(org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, mediaType));

 }
```

At the end the schema are not registrer in the component.
It seems there is several problem.  I don't add the sub class and also schema disapears from openAPi bean. It seems there is a new component. I can see it in another method which implements OpenApiCustomiser

Thank you for your help